# Problem getting ASP.NET Core Google login to work

Tags: asp.net-core, google-signin

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web app, in which I want to add Google login.

I followed this description:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0

When I run the app, choosing the Google login button/option, adding my mail to the login screen at the Google site (https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier ...) I get to the next page which says:

> This browser or app may not be secure. ...

I tried a few things of editing settings at my apps Google credentials page (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/).

I have added: https://localhost:7049 for the "Authorized JavaScript origins" part and: https://localhost:7049/signin-google for the "Authorized redirect URIs" part.

Am I missing something else that's important here?

Thanks for any assistance!

Updated with picture of my settings in the Google Console.
[image: Settings for the Google Console]

Updated with my settings in the "OAuth consent screen":
[image: OAuth consent screen settings]
I have added two email addresses and have tried both to login. No luck here ...

Update. This code is added in the Program.cs file:

```
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    // For compatibility between platforms ":" shall be
    // replaced with "__" / double underscore
    IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
        builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
    // Instead use ( TODO ???, BOTH seems to work ..):
    // options.ClientId = 
        configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    // options.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    // When to use ":" and when to use "__" ???
    // Probably in the config file (that do not seem to work!? ...) ???
        options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
    })
```

and also added this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Referrer-Policy", "no-referrer-when-downgrade");
    await next();
});
```

The last piece is in relation to the info written here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid

It says:

> When you perform local tests or development, you must add both http://localhost and http://localhost:<port_number> to the Authorized JavaScript origins box. The Referrer-Policy header must also be set to no-referrer-when-downgrade when using http and localhost.

Unsure what this exactly does or means, or if it is relevant in my case.

A short description how I got her is something like this:

- Followed this description at Microsoft:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0
  and this description at Google:
  https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid
- Created an ASP.NET CORE app with authentication. .NET 7 with latest version of C#. Added the Nuget package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google
- Created a project at the Google site for developers (https://console.cloud.google.com/) and added there the OAuth 2.0 Client credentials parts with the added URIs as in the picture above. Also added/edited the settings at the "OAuth consent screen" page. See above!
- Added the key and link for the created Google OAuth 2.0 credentials to the "developer local storage" as described in the Microsoft link which makes it possible to use the "configuration" parts in my added code for the Program.cs file.
- Added the code as described above.
- Started the web app and then tried to use my own two Google accounts to login. I get to the point where you add your email adress and continue. And here I get the message "This browser or app may not be secure. ...".

A note here is that I have my Google account set for two factor authentication. There are a few links and videos online that says that this can cause this problem. And here they reference that you need to enable "unsecure app login" and due to this remove the two factor authentication. However! You can now no longer disable this at the Google site as of last year (I think it was last year ...). And it seems strange/not ok that this solution should Not support two factor login when this is more or less the general standard to increase your accounts security!?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Stefan, could you  [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I am willing to check it. Please using *** to replcae the sensitive info if you have.

Comment: @JasonPan thanks for your reply! I have tried to add the steps how it shall be possible to reproduce this problem. I also added some notes on some own found information in relation to this. Very thankful for your assist!

Answer (score 4):

Setting in Google Console.

[image]

[image]

Your code in Program.cs file should be like below:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = "103****7s.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = "GOCSPX-****_b3-jMPKHe";
}).AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = "b3fb++_if_you_have_++c5fe2d";
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = "R****cbku";
});
```

**Test Result**

[image]

Comment: I now added a picture of my current settings in the Google Console.
Plus, also the code added in Program.cs.
No progress from there ...

Comment: What about SPA ? how would we do it there

Comment: Dear @DživoJelić, please post a new thread, if someone familiar with that, they will help you.

Comment: thx but i managed to do it i will make a post about it

Comment: @DživoJelić: Do you have a link to that post or any source code repo? We have the same problem and don't get it working with SPA (angular)

Comment: @carstinho yes i was able to do it. For some reason i was able to name callback function sam as the ms and it didnt work. As soon as i changed callback function path name and updated it in google console it started working. Be sure to wait 5 min after updating callback urls

Comment: @JasonPan I agree but dont have time to that right now. SPA is mostly disregarded by ms we need more angular react vue examples with common things in ASP NET. Better docs = better framework and saves developers a lot of time